# W3 Total Cache: .woff and .otf font files not uploading to CDN?

Tags: wordpress, caching, fonts, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using W3 Total Cache in WordPress to transfer all of my static files to CloudFront. All file types work properly, except for .woff and .otf font files. Here's how W3TC is configured to handle CloudFront:

[image]

Any idea why I might be missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to [GNASCHENWENG](http://naschenweng.info). Turns out the file-extension separators after .woff and .otf were commas, when they needed to be semi-colons:

[image]

Fonts uploaded successfully to CloudFront now.

Comment: Just saved me a load of time!  Seems it is a bug in the default installation of the plugin.

Comment: Man, thanks for posting it!!!! It was driving me crazy!! This is a ridiculous bug, even more because the default configuration comes like this. Thanks a lot!